# How to display current date in input control based on timezone?

Tags: angular, date, datetime, angular-material, datepicker

I have an input control with startAt="CalendarDate" where I want to display current date based on the timezone.The control is displaying yesterday's date.Pls let me know how to correct this

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="SelectedDate" [min]="minDate" startAt="CalendarDate" (dateChange)="getByDate()" readonly="readonly">
<mat-datepicker #picker [(ngModel)]="SelectedDate"></mat-datepicker>  

 calDate= this.CommonService.GetDateTimeByTimeZone().subscribe(tz => {
     this.timezoneDate = tz;
     this.SelectedDate = moment(this.timezoneDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  });
  CalendarDate = this.calDate;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `this.CommonService.GetDateTimeByTimeZone()` does.

Comment: Hey, please have a look at the official docs: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats . This covers date formatting.